# Stabilisers in non-abelian $p$-groups are contained in non-transitive maximal abelian subgroups?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, permutations, maximal-subgroup

Let $P$ be a non-abelian finite $p$-group which is a transitive permutation group of degree $p^n$ such that the stabiliser of a point is meet-irreducible.

Suppose $P$ has a non-transitive abelian maximal subgroup $M$.

I am told that if $S$ is a stabiliser of a point in $P$ then $S\le M$, since $M$ is non-transitive and I am trying to understand why?

Obviously if $S\not\le M$ then $<S,M>=P$ which is transitive. Is there a contradiction here?

Comment: Is S maximal in the set of all subgroups or only in the set of non-transitive abelian subgroups?

Comment: I believe $M$ (I assume you mean $M$ not $S$) is assumed to be non-transitive and maximal in the set of abelian subgroups, but if it can be shown using maximal among all subgroups, that would still be interesting

Comment: I will assume $M$ is maximal in the set of all subgroups

Comment: Maximal subgroups of $p$-groups have index $p$, so if $M$ is intransitive then it must contain $S$ or else, by the Orbit-Stabilizer Theorem, it would have index greater than $p$ in $G$. That doesn't use the fact that $M$ is abelian or that $S$ is meet-irreducible,

Comment: I thought I must have forgotten something simple like that, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer provided by Derek Holt in comments (rewritten and details added here to get full answer):

Maximal subgroups of $p$-groups have index $p$. Suppose $S=Stab_G(x)$ and notice $Stab_M(x)=S\cap M$, then by the Orbit-stabilizer Theorem $|G|=|S||x^G|$ and $|M|=|M\cap S||x^M|$. This gives $p=|G:M|=\frac{|G|}{|M|}=\frac{|S||x^G|}{|M\cap S||x^M|}$. Since $G$ is transitive and $M$ is intransitive $\frac{|x^G|}{|x^M|}> 1$, which is only possible if $|S|=|S\cap M|$. Hence $S\le M$.